# What is the difference between maxIdleTime and maxLifeTime in Netty HttpClient?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor-netty

According to [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_connection_pool):

> **maxIdleTime** - The time after which the channel is eligible to be
> closed when idle (resolution: ms). Default: max idle time is not
> specified.
>
> **maxLifeTime** - The total life time after which the channel is eligible
> to be closed (resolution: ms). Default: max life time is not
> specified.

When will my connection be closed if I define my `ConnectionProvider` like this?

```java
ConnectionProvider.builder("fixed")
    .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
    .build()
```

After 20 seconds? At least after 20 seconds?

What if I define it like this?

```java
ConnectionProvider.builder("fixed")
    .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
    .build()
```

What is the difference and what should I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxLifeTime` defines the max lifetime of connections. For example, where connections to a load-balancer should not always be reused because its IP address has changed due to resource changes so new connections should end up at the new IP based on underlying DNS updates.

`maxIdleTime` defines the max idle time of connections. For example, after 20 minutes of idle time, the connection will be closed.

Comment: About the `maxIdleTime` example. So, in my example I can be sure that it will be closed in 20 seconds? The "will be eligible" part tells me that it likely will not.

Comment: it is not strict, it is either checked when the connection is released back to the pool or via a background reaper thread that can be configured with `.evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(x))`